# Statistical tests for no overlap between lists (not for overlap)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have to show there is no significant overlap between two gene lists. 
The way I did was to show high p value of the overlap (from hypergeometric test) and show that I can't reject the null hypothesis of no significant overlap.

But the critique says being unable to reject the null hypothesis doesn't necessarily prove the inverse that no significant overlap exists. In theory, I understand the comment, but I can't think of a test that directly estimates p value of no significant overlap (or significance of absence of overlap).